# The Text on The Alert

Tags: javascript, alert

We can take the text from elements on the web by using document.getElementbyId("...") or different methods. However I can not get the text on the alertbox. I understant that alert is not a web element. So how can I take the text on the alert box by using javascript?
Thanks.
I try to automatize a process, so I need to the text in an alert in some steps of the process

Comment: You call `alert("some text")`, so * you decide* what's in there. Why do you need to get it afterwards (JS does not run while the alet is open)?

Comment: Show  your code ?

Comment: get text in variable and pass it to alert.

Comment: *how can I take the text on the alert box by using javascript?* Please add more context on this statement. Are you looking for way to read the text on alert or you wish to read an element's text and show on alert box?

Comment: I am trying to automatize a process, I encounter with alert and need to the text on the alert

Answer (score 2):

Try this code:

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <title>Text on Alertbox</title>
    <script type="text/javascript">
        function display()
        {
            var str=document.getElementById("txt").innerHTML;
            alert(str);
        }
    </script>
</head>
<body>
<p id="txt"> Hello World!! </p>
<button type="button" onclick="display()"> Click Here </button>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

I believe that you want to get the text in alert box. If that is the case you can get that text value when you are trying to show it in alert box.

example:

```
//you have got your alert text here itself
    var content = "Alert content";
    alert(content);
```

Why are you trying to reverse the process of getting text from alert

Answer (score 0):

```js
  function callFunction() {
    var someValue = document.getElementById("someId").value;
    alert(someValue);
  }
```

```html
<input type="text" id="someId" onchange="callFunction()"><br>
```